# "execution reverted: ERC20: call failed"

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, swaps, transferfrom, bridge

I try to call the swap function in X bridge but it is not working mysteriously. so contract X (which is the bridge) is calling a handler inside internally and the transfer method is happening there. I transferred my token to my contract and then approve the handler contract, but it throw the "execution reverted: ERC20: call failed" error to me. Does anybody know what the problem is?

this is my contract code:

```
Ix{
  function deposit(uint8 a, bytes32 b, bytes calldata data) external payable returns (bytes memory);
}
contract Z{
    address handler= 0x000;
    address x= 0x000;
    function swap(uint8 a,bytes32 b,address srcToken, uint256 srcAmount,address recipientAddress)
    external payable {
                     
        IERC20(srcToken).transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this),srcAmount);  
        IERC20(srcToken).approve(handelIce, srcAmount);
 
        bytes memory data = abi.encodePacked(srcAmount, uint256(20), recipientAddress);
        IX(X).deposit(a,b,data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably include the full code including the imports and state variable declarations in order to understand where the error might be, but one problem might be in the last line of the function: 'IX(contractX).deposit(a,b,data);'  You mention a contractX which appears to be the address of IX, but not a "contractX" isn't defined in this snippet (neither a param, local or defined state variable) so not clear where either contract IX or variable contractX are coming  from.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I import the interface of the bridge and use the interface and in the last line instead of contract x I meant xbrdige address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with the interface, it did not return anything and I used the handler's interface.